# How do I bind a callback function on the complete jstree reload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a button that reloads (resends an AJAX request) the jsTree once is clicked.

Here is a sample configuration code I have:

```
treeContainer.bind("loaded.jstree", function () {
    alert("the tree is loaded");
}).jstree(config);
```

The problem I experience is that I do not have the alert (wrapped in a callback function) displayed once the 'reload' button is clicked the 2nd, 3rd, etc. times.
Am I using the wrong jstree status event?

To summarize, I want a jsTree callback function to be executed each time I click the 'reload' button.

I am currently using **jsTree 1.0-rc1 (rev. 191)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's an old  question, but I ran into the same problem with jsTree 3.3.4. Solution that works is:

```
treeContainer.bind("refresh.jstree", function (event, data) {
    alert("the tree has been refreshed");
    $(this).jstree("open_all");  //Example: open all nodes after refreshing
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Destroying the tree before building the new one works as well.

```
treeContainer.jstree("destroy");
treeContainer.bind("loaded.jstree", function () {
    alert("the tree is loaded");
}).jstree(config);
```

Comment: Thank you.  The simplicity of this and the fact that it was the only method I could get to work makes me very happy.

Answer (score 1):

add this to the core:

```
        reopen : function () {
            var _this = this;
            if(this.data.core.to_open.length) {
                $.each(this.data.core.to_open, function (i, val) {
                    _this.open_node(val, false, true); 
                });
            }
            this.__callback({});
            this.reopened();
        },
```

note that only this.reopened is added to the allready existing reopen-method. now create the reopened-method:

```
        reopened : function () {
            this.__callback();
        },
```

now bind the new reopened-method to your tree-selector

```
}).bind("reopened.jstree", function (e,data) {
        alert("i am refreshed...");
    });
```

be carefull, because this alert-message will also be called when the tree is done loading.
It is anyhow better, since you now have a way to have a callback when the tree is refreshed!

hope this helps you all!

Answer (score -1):

From the [jstree documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core):

> .loaded ()
>
> A dummy function, whose purpose is
>   only to trigger the loaded event. This
>   event is triggered once after the
>   tree's root nodes are loaded, but
>   before any nodes set in initially_open
>   are opened.

So you can call this method from the success callback of your ajax call. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourscript-url",
  success: function(){
    $('selector-for-jstree-container').jstree('loaded');
  }
});
```

See also the "***Interacting with the tree***" section on the same jstree documentation page.

Comment: this is not quite what I needed... I want to keep my jsTree-related configurations in one place. the thing I'm looking for is an event like this: `treeContainer.bind("reloaded.jstree", function () {...}).jstree(...)`

Comment: @John Doe I'm sorry but I don't think there is an event like this in jstree. You'll either have to work your way around that (similarly as I suggested) or extend the jstree core and implement this new event.